# Pegar domínio via Node/Vue.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js

Quero simplesmente que ao acessar a página seja mostrado o domínio que aparece ali na URL.

`window.location.hostname` me dá isso, só que não funciona no Node/Vue.js, então qual seria a solução?

Comment: Luciano, caso alguma resposta tenha resolvido o seu problema você pode marcar como aceita clicando no V verdinho do lado dos pontos da escolhida. Ou, caso queira, pode deixar em aberto mais um tempo se deseja mais alternativas, mas é bom que depois de resolvida você marque alguma para fechar o assunto. Saiba mais em ["Como e por que aceitar uma resposta"](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta).

Answer (score 3):

Não se entendi a sua pergunta, até por que não está clara o suficiente. Mas para pegar o domínio você pode utilizar uma propriedade Javascript que retorna o domínio da página.

```
document.domain
```

Ao executar isso no console do so você terá o seguinte retorno:

```
"pt.stackoverflow.com"
```

Para mais informações você pode acessar essa documentação clicando [aqui](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/domain).